# Removing an object in Hibernate/JPA and nullify children automatic

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cascade

Is it possible with JPA to automatically nullify children when deleting the parent?
I have a Model Class Device, with sync statistics attached to it. When I remove the device I still want to keep the statistics, so put the field device in the Statistics class to 'null'.

```
@OneToMany (mappedBy = "device", fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
public List<Statistic> syncStats;
```

and

```
@ManyToOne (fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
public Device device;
```

Is there an automatic way of obtaining this effect or do I have to do it manually?

Currently I use:

```
@PreRemove
protected void removeLinkToStats() {
    syncStats.clear();
}
```

but this still gives a "A javax.persistence.PersistenceException has been caught, org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update"

Comment: You aren't allowed to access/change other Entites in the LifeCycle callback methods (it is in the JPA spec), that is why you are getting the Exception. What happens if you just do absolutely nothing about this except use orphanRemoval=false?

Comment: No, I still get the same error: A javax.persistence.PersistenceException has been caught, org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update

Comment: Well, the following seems works. If you want to suggest it as answer then I accept it for pointing me in the direction:
    @PreRemove
    public void testing() {
        for(Statistic stat : syncStats){
            stat.device = null;
            stat.save();
        }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible with JPA to automatically nullify children when deleting the parent?

No. With JPA it is the application's responsibility to keep sync. Your application should call business logic before removing the entity using JPA.

Of course there are multiple ways of doing so. Using annotations like PreRemove or PreDestroy or (my personal favorite) do your pre removal things in a business container wich calls your data access to remove the entity from the database.

Short example:

```
class Business
{
    DataAccess dataAccess;
    //.....

    public void removeEntity(Entity e)
    {
        //do pre removal here
        dataAccess.remove(e);
    }
    //......
}

class DataAccess
{
    EntityManager em;

    //......

    public void remove(Entity e)
    {
        em.remove(e);
    }

    //....
}
```